# Getting xml Attribute value in Linq with Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, lambda

Let us consider the following xml Structure as

```
  <membership defaultProvider="SQLMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SQLMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SQLMembershipConnString" applicationName=".NET Pet Shop 4.0" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

i have checked with the following code whether type contains "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" follows as

```
 var prop1 = prop.Descendants(ns + "add").First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider");
```

my query is to get the attribute value of connectionStringName with the above query

waiting for your responses

Comment: Have you confirmed that `ns` contains the expected namespace prefix (from your example XML, none) and have you tried accessing the just casting `p.Attribute("type")` to a `string`?

Comment: @M.Babcock i have retried ns value  as   var ns = xDoc.Descendants().First(x => x.Name.LocalName == "configuration").Name.Namespace;

Comment: @M.Babcock i have tried it but getting error cannot convert form string to bool like tat can u provide me some structure

Comment: @M.Babcock my need is to get the value of connectionStringName form above xml

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? 
`var connStringName = prop1.Attribute("connectionStringName").Value;`

Comment: @publicgk thanks that wat i messed it

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var prop1 = xmldoc.Descendants("add").First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider").Attribute("connectionStringName").Value;
```

Hope this will help you...